# Is knowing Microsoft Office programs a plus for game producers or do they have to know them well?

Tags: project-management, career

I've been told that they should know them, but I've also been told that it's a plus.

Comment: Related: [Spreadsheets in Game Design?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/40377/spreadsheets-in-game-design)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is.

However, *how much* knowing Office matters, or what level of knowledge is considered "knowing," is going to depend very much on the specific company looking to fill a production role and even potentially on what that actual role will be doing a the studio.

If the role is at a studio that exclusively uses Office and related products and infrastructure for its production management pipeline, then knowing it at some level will likely be a requirement and knowing it in great depth will likely be a plus.

If the role is at a studio that exclusively uses Google Documents and related products and infrastructure for its production management pipeline, then knowing Office will probably not be a requirement, but might be a minor perk if you don't know anything about Google's systems because you could (presumably) use your knowledge of Office to make educated guesses about how Google's stuff worked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how exactly do you know this?

Comment: @SebastianNen-Calamar I've worked in the industry for more than a decade, at multiple companies, some of which I've been extensively involved in the hiring process and evaluation of candidates in multiple roles for. I also have a reasonably large network of industry contacts and colleagues, and hiring "stuff," including topics like what you're asking about, is a common topic of discussion.

Comment: I can do very basic things in Excel but that's about it. Do you think that might be a dealbreaker or does it not really matter?

Comment: I don't really want to speculate on specific scenarios; that's not really what SE is for. You could ask in [chat] or on a site like [GDNet](http://www.gamedev.net) if you wanted some specific advice tailored to your scenario. In broad terms, I doubt it would hurt much but it won't be a benefit for you.